# Cannot Read Property 'top' occurs when click button to open modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

The following code works when the page loads.  However when I click on a button that is supposed to open a modal window I get the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

How can I fix this error?

```
if ($(window).width() > 992) {

    (function($) {
        "use strict";
        $(".page-scroll a[href^='#'], #intro a").on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var hash = this.hash;
            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top - 100}, 2000, 'easeOutExpo');
        });
    })(jQuery);

    $('body').scrollspy({
        target: '.navbar',
        offset: 110
    });
    // alert("large");
}
else {

    (function($) {
        "use strict";
        $(".page-scroll a[href^='#'], #intro a").on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var hash = this.hash;
            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top - 50}, 2000, 'easeOutExpo');
        });
    })(jQuery);

    $('body').scrollspy({
        target: '.navbar',
        offset: 70
    });
    // alert("small");
}   

//modal popup function
function popup_modal(item){
    var link = $(item).attr('id');
    $('#bootstrap_modal').load('/'+link+'');
    $('#bootstrap_modal').modal('show'); 
    $("#bootstrap_modal").on("show", function () {
        $("body").addClass("modal-open");
    }).on("hidden", function () {
        $("body").removeClass("modal-open")
    });
}

//Modal pop up
$('.mmodal').on('click', function(){
    popup_modal(this);
});
```

Comment: Would be great to see html as well, it should be something to do with $(hash).offset().top - 50}, 2000, 'easeOutExpo');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probable reason you are getting the error, that `$(hash)` element doesn't exist for the case of your modal button. And modal button is an element that falls into `$(".page-scroll a[href^='#'], #intro a").on('click')` event. if there's no element with id that equals "href" attribute of the clicked button you can't get it's "offset.top". 
Put "`console.log(hash)`" to check what you get there.

A Possible solution:

```
if ($(hash).length) {
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
         scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top - 100}, 2000, 'easeOutExpo');
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it produces a strange error 'unexpected token )'  I typed it exactly as you show above

Comment: I made a syntax error, my bad. Have a look now, It shouldn't return any error. Additionally, it would be nice to have your example in jsfiddle or something like that. It's difficult to debug without knowing what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below:

```
if ($(window).width() > 992) {

    (function($) {
        "use strict";
        $(".page-scroll a[href^='#'], #intro a").on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var hash = this.hash;
            var newVal = $(hash).offset().top - 100;
            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: newVal}, 2000, 'easeOutExpo');
        });
    })(jQuery);

    $('body').scrollspy({
        target: '.navbar',
        offset: 110
    });
    // alert("large");
}
else {

    (function($) {
        "use strict";
        $(".page-scroll a[href^='#'], #intro a").on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var hash = this.hash;
            var newVal = $(hash).offset().top - 50;
            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: newVal}, 2000, 'easeOutExpo');
        });
    })(jQuery);

    $('body').scrollspy({
        target: '.navbar',
        offset: 70
    });
    // alert("small");
}   

//modal popup function
function popup_modal(item){
    var link = $(item).attr('id');
    $('#bootstrap_modal').load('/'+link+'');
    $('#bootstrap_modal').modal('show'); 
    $("#bootstrap_modal").on("show", function () {
        $("body").addClass("modal-open");
    }).on("hidden", function () {
        $("body").removeClass("modal-open")
    });
}

//Modal pop up
$('.mmodal').on('click', function(){
    popup_modal(this);
});
```

I have set the variable `newVal` to the value of `$(hash).offset().top - 50`